# Resizing HTMLLoader size lags behind position

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, tween

I am trying to resize and reposition a `HTMLLoader` by the same amount,  but the size of the `HTMLLoader` always lags behind the position by at least a frame. The position and size are both changing by the same amount. This happens both when changing the size manually, and when using tweens. I tried delaying the tweens that control position by a frame, and it sometimes helped, but other times made it worse.

tween code:

```
// t is the time, 0.5 in this case
// ease is the easing function, I tried linear and Regular.easeInOut
tweenW  = new Tween(gallery.masker, "width", ease, gallery.masker.width, (full ? largeX : smallX), t, true);
tweenH  = new Tween(gallery.masker, "height", ease, gallery.masker.height, (full ? largeY : smallY), t, true);
tweenX  = new Tween(gallery.masker, "x", ease, gallery.masker.x, (full ? -posX : 0), t, true);
tweenY  = new Tween(gallery.masker, "y", ease, gallery.masker.y, (full ? -posY : 0), t, true);
tweenBX = new Tween(border, "x", ease, border.x, (full ? 0 : posX), t, true);
tweenBY = new Tween(border, "y", ease, border.y, (full ? 0 : posY), t, true);
tweenBW = new Tween(border, "width", ease, border.width, (full ? largeX * borderMultX : smallX * borderMultX), t, true);
tweenBH = new Tween(border, "height", ease, border.height, (full ? largeY * borderMultY : smallY * borderMultY), t, true);
```

`HTMLLoader` resize code (Event.EXIT_FRAME):

```
loader.width = gallery.masker.width;
loader.height = gallery.masker.height;
loader.x = gallery.masker.x;
loader.y = gallery.masker.y;
```

When displayed, the size  of `gallery.masker` is correct, but the `HTMLLoader` still lags behind

example:

the HTML content is an empty green page, `gallery.masker` is a red shape with 50% alpha above the `HTMLLoader`. The tween is about halfway done expanding.

(its not letting me post images, could someone please edit this? http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/3699/resizeq.png )

EDIT: a minimal example is available at http://www.mediafire.com/?5c2zkhmb6v9b61u (contains CS6 .fla, all source, .swf, and app.xml)

Comment: `tweenW, tweenH, tweenX...` they are global variables or function level variables? I'm asking because looks like garbage collector is removing these tween objects from memory, before they finish their job. Make sure you keep reference on these tween objects until they are finished. This is common issue with tweening engine from `fl` package.

Comment: I use a nested function. The tweens are always completing, the `HTMLLoader` just seems to not keep up properly.  
`private function SetupResize(/*vars*/) {/* ... */ var tweenX:Tween; /* .. */ function DoTween(t:Number) { /* tweens here */ } }`

Answer (score 0):

Tweening engine from `fl` package have known issue, reference on each `Tween` object should be kept until it is finished, otherwise in most cases garbage collector removes these objects before they can finish heir job. Thus properties on target/tweened object are freezed.

@Malik Drako in your case you can make references on `Tween` objects global to keep them always alive, or more flexible way will be to take one `Vector` and make some pull mechanism for references, so in second case you don't need to name every `Tween` object and same time you can create as many `Tween`s as you want.

Comment: To make it more clear when your function finishes executing (I'm about `SetupResize()`) it's variables became eligible for garbage collector.

Comment: I have seen that issue, but that is not what is happening here. Here, the tweens always complete.

Comment: I also tried manually changing the size in AS and the size still lags behind